# Prepare step isn't being executed

Tags: semantic-release

I'm currently trying to setup `semantic-release` to publish `package.json` with the updated version and `CHANGELOG` to both npm and GitHub. From what I've read, this seem possible using [@semantic-release/git](https://github.com/semantic-release/git) and [@semantic-release/changelog](https://github.com/semantic-release/changelog) plugins. However, I couldn't make it work with my configs. My package is something like that: (source @ [redux-form-input-masks](https://github.com/renato-bohler/redux-form-input-masks/blob/master/package.json))

```
(...)
"devDependencies": {
    "@semantic-release/changelog": "^1.0.1",
    "@semantic-release/git": "^3.0.1",
    "semantic-release": "^13.4.1",
    (...)
},
"release": {
  "debug": true,
  "verifyConditions": [
    "@semantic-release/changelog",
    "@semantic-release/npm",
    "@semantic-release/git",
    "@semantic-release/github"
  ],
  "prepare": [
    "@semantic-release/changelog",
    "@semantic-release/npm",
    {
      "path": "@semantic-release/git",
      "assets": [
        "package.json",
        "CHANGELOG.md"
      ],
      "message": "chore(release): ${nextRelease.version} [skip ci]\n\n${nextRelease.notes}"
    }
    ],
    "publish": [
        "@semantic-release/npm",
        "@semantic-release/github"
    ]
}
(...)
```

And the Travis CI build log shows:

```
[0Ktravis_fold:start:after_success.2
[0Ktravis_time:start:0014f334
[0K$ npx semantic-release
[Semantic release]: Running semantic-release version 13.4.1
[Semantic release]: Load plugin verifyConditions from @semantic-release/changelog
[Semantic release]: Load plugin verifyConditions from @semantic-release/npm
[Semantic release]: Load plugin verifyConditions from @semantic-release/git
[Semantic release]: Load plugin verifyConditions from @semantic-release/github
[Semantic release]: Load plugin analyzeCommits from @semantic-release/commit-analyzer
[Semantic release]: Load plugin generateNotes from @semantic-release/release-notes-generator
[Semantic release]: Load plugin publish from @semantic-release/npm
[Semantic release]: Load plugin publish from @semantic-release/github
[Semantic release]: Run automated release from branch master
[Semantic release]: Call plugin verify-conditions
[Semantic release]: Verify authentication for registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
[Semantic release]: Wrote NPM_TOKEN to .npmrc.
[Semantic release]: Verify GitHub authentication
[Semantic release]: Found git tag v0.3.5 associated with version 0.3.5
[Semantic release]: Found 1 commits since last release
[Semantic release]: Call plugin analyze-commits
[Semantic release]: Analyzing commit: fix: testing semantic-release
[Semantic release]: The release type for the commit is patch
[Semantic release]: Analysis of 1 commits complete: patch release
[Semantic release]: The next release version is 0.3.6
[Semantic release]: Call plugin verify-release
[Semantic release]: Call plugin generateNotes
[Semantic release]: Create tag v0.3.6
[Semantic release]: Call plugin publish
[Semantic release]: Wrote version 0.3.6 to package.json
[Semantic release]: Wrote version 0.3.6 to package-lock.json
[Semantic release]: Publishing version 0.3.6 to npm registry
+ redux-form-input-masks@0.3.6[Semantic release]: Published GitHub release: https://github.com/renato-bohler/redux-form-input-masks/releases/tag/v0.3.6
[Semantic release]: Published release: 0.3.6

travis_time:end:0014f334:start=1519095849162192955,finish=1519095858417255129,duration=9255062174
[0Ktravis_fold:end:after_success.2
```

This does publish a new tag and release on both GitHub and npm, but it doesn't create a `CHANGELOG.md` (as I'm expecting from changelog plugin) and it doesn't commit the `package.json` with the updated version (0.3.6 in this case - as I'm expecting from git plugin).

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally made it work.

The problem was that `npm i @semantic-release/git --save-dev` would install the git plugin at version 3.0.1, and I was reading the [API for for version 4.0.0](https://github.com/semantic-release/git/blob/master/README.md).

To solve it, I did

```
npm i --save-dev semantic-release@15 @semantic-release/git@4 @semantic-release/changelog@2
```